# Grafana loki plot parsed numeric values

Tags: grafana-loki

I am trying to perform a simple task in Grafana Loki. Fluentd has already parsed a csv log and put it in Loki. There are four fields in this csv, one of which is duration. Duration is a number in nanoseconds. I want to plot a time series of this values without any aggregations.
[image]
In the above example I basically need to parse a number from string "287511" and plot it on a time series chart. I tried to use the following query, but it didn't work.
`{job="order_durations"} | unwrap duration`. What is the right way to do it?

Thank you